# SingleInstance activity launched from notification, on backPressed, comes out of app

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, activity-lifecycle, launchmode

I have 3 activities in my app: A, B, C.
A launches B, B launches C.
C's launch mode is SingleInstance(declared in manifest).

**Steps:** 1.When I am on C, I show notification in notification bar, onclick of which launch same screen.
2. I put my app in background by pressing home.
3. When I tap on notification, C gets launched.

**Question:** When I press back on C, I come out of my application. Instead, I should go back to earlier screen of my app, i.e. B

**Note: I have declared C as singleInstance, because I don't want multiple instances of C getting launched on tap of notification.** I have handled same instance, with **OnNewIntent()**, by refreshing UI with corresponding data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: posat your manifest please

Answer (score 1):

Use the default launch mode of `standard` for Activity C.

In the intent used to build the `PendingIntent` for your notification, add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

The existing instance of activity C will be resumed and the `onNewIntent()` method called.